# Empty space appended while using msdropdown (in Chrome Browser)

Tags: jquery, msdropdown

I used msdropdown with my web app, i noticed that it created a empty space with a long-scroll at the bottom. Once i removed the drop-down, no issue. so i'm sure its form msdropdown. any help on this,,,

In there demo itself it shows the long scroll. check this [Demo](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/image-dropdown/samples/index.html) in chrome

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and I've found out that this starts to happen when there are more than 70 elements in the selectbox.

I have tested it with this small piece of code:

```
var newhtml = "";
var start = 2013;
for (var x = 0; x < 70; x ++) {
    newhtml += "<option value='"+(start-x)+"'>"+(start-x)+"</option>";
}
$(this).html(newhtml);
$(this).msDropDown ();
```

With this code, no whitespace is added to the page.
If I change '70' to '71' however, whitespace is added.

Edit: It appears to be a problemn with the '.ddChild' element. I have added a "height: 0px" to the css and my problem is gone.
This still happens with a large number of elements, but the exact amount of elements depends on the body height.